# Immutability in aggregate child entities

Tags: nested, entity, domain-driven-design

I have begun using domain driven design principles but are currently stuck with a specific problem.

I have an Aggregate which has multiple layers of nested child entities as shown below:

```cs
public class Aggregate: Entity<AggregateId>, IAggregateRoot {
    private readonly List<ChildOne> childOnes;
}

public class ChildOne: Entity<ChildOneId> {
    public string ChildOneValue1;
    public string ChildOneValue2;
    public string ChildOneValue3;
    private readonly List<ChildTwo> childTwos;
}

public class ChildTwo: Entity<ChildTwoId> {
    public string ChildTwoValue1;
    public string ChildTwoValue2;
    public string ChildTwoValue3;
}
```

In a domain service I need to access all values of `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` including their ids.

```cs
public interface IDomainService {
    public IEnumerable<INotification> Analyze(Aggregate aggregate);
}
```

However, I cannot return the entities as they are since this would violate the immutability principle.

This got me thinking that my domain model probably might not be optimal, but I cannot see how this can be different since the nested entities never can exist without the respective parent.

Another approach could be to have a single value object which holds all values of a given entity and then return this value object instead of the entity. But then a deep mapping needs to be performed since the domain service needs access to the values of all nested entities.

Any suggestions on to how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on to how to approach this?

There are a couple of possibilities.

One is to invert your proposed API - design the domain service to accept immutable values as arguments, and then pass the instance of that service to the Aggregate, rather than the other way around.

```
public interface IDomainService {
    public IEnumerable<INotification> Analyze(IEnumerable<DomainValue> values);
}
```

If you recall the `Visitor` pattern from the Gang of Four book, it is a very similar idea.

In some cases, an in-memory state machine might be a reasonable alternative to a stateless domain service.  In that case, the API might look like

```
public interface IDomainService {
    public void OnAnalyze(DomainValue value);
    public IEnumerable<INotification> Notifications();
}
```

Another possibility is to design the Aggregate to act as a Collection

```
public class Aggregate {
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<DomainValue> YourCleverNameHere();
}
```

For use cases where you are not changing the state of the Aggregate, just leave the aggregate out of it, and work directly with an immutable in memory representation of the current state.

Comment: The problem is that  in order to perform the analysis the domain service needs all values from the `ChildOne` collection along with the values from the nested `ChildTwo` entities at once. Since nested structure is important for the domain service I cannot pass all values as a list. As far as I can see the only solution is perform a deep mapping of all child entities into a hierarchy of value objects and pass this to the domain service.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I cannot return the entities as they are since this would violate the immutability principle.

The entites don't need to be immutable. It's only value object that are immutable in tactical design of domain driven design.

As far as entities are aggregates are concerned, you should be able to get/save an aggregate from the repository only using the aggregate root. You should not be able to get/save an entity that is not an aggregate root.

Comment: I am aware that child entities doesn't have to be immutable. What I meant was that if I return a child entity, I will in fact return an mutable object which can be altered outside of its aggregate root. However, a solution could be to map all `ChildOne` along with its nested child entities into a hierachy of immutable value objects and return them instead. But I am not sure this is the optimal solution.

Comment: When you return the child entity, the aggregate can still hold the reference to it. So the aggregate can know if the object is mutated. The entity can be persisted by the reference to the aggregate root at the end of the transaction

Comment: You are right - I hadn't thought of it that way. However, I havn't seen this technique mentioned anywhere so even though this could work I am wondering if this is best practice? I really appreciate your help, but since I am new in domain driven design I strive to follow best practices :)

Comment: How are you versioning you aggregates? This is very important